# Visual studio i think heap error

Tags: c++, winapi

I am on a project with C++ and WinApi32 . There Are 3 classes , each of them is about 150 
lines code .

In my main window , below code will be ran frequently :

```
wc.cbClsExtra=0;
wc.cbWndExtra=0;
wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(BkColor);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_HAND);
wc.hIcon = NULL;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
vertex_hInstance = hInstance;
wc.lpfnWndProc = VertexProc;
wc.lpszClassName = Vertex_Class;
wc.lpszMenuName=NULL;
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
RegisterClass(&wc);
hWnd = CreateWindow(Vertex_Class,L"",WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,getx(),gety(),getw(),geth(),parent_HWND,NULL,hInstance,0);
```

It's in a function of a class which I have defined early. Running Program : There is no error , everything is good. Closing Program : gives me error :**Windows Has Triggered a Breakpoint**, to see picture :
[Visit Error](http://www.ecapic.ir/image3/ECA-110203204056.png)

Comment: The image is an arabic (or something like that)

Comment: Why is that code run frequently?  You only need to register that class once...

Comment: @Alf - I opened the page and translated it with google translate - it only makes me upload some file and shows what are the limitations of the file, that I can upload. Nothing else.

Comment: @Alf: Coming from a site in Iran, I suggest it’s rather more likely to be Persian than Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown is not sufficient to say what causes the problem that you describe.

However, you should not register the same window class more than once.

I don't know the effect of "frequently" registering the same window class, because it's just not something that one does (so I have no experience with that), but conceivably it *might* be gobbling up resources, which in turn might have a very detrimental effect…

The usual solution is register a window class only the first time, or before you create any windows of that class.

E.g. you can use a singleton to achieve this.

Cheers & hth.,